# careers.stackoverflow.com needs an 'off' button

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

So I put my name in your database to have a look at the system, but there's no 'off' button. I'm quite happy where I am at the moment thank-you-very-much.

How about implementing an off button at the same time as changing the pricing: $9 per month that it's turned 'on'. That way, when I'm looking for work I'm paying. When I'm not looking, I'm not paying.

Comment: I was just about to ask this question.  The FAQ wasn't quite clear about this.  I'd like to get the cheap initial pricing, but have no immediate interest in changing jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be the ability to make your CV private.

Comment: +1. Not sure the down-voter realized what you were saying -- especially since the question has two questions in one.

Comment: Accepted the answer after listening to the latest podcast which gives a lot more information about the intentions than the site itself does :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can make your CV private at any time, which indicates you're "in a relationship", as they say.

Payment to list your CV covers a certain time period, regardless of whether or not you're actively looking for work.